# Hyperledger Fabric on Ubuntu Linux 16.04 VM not running

Tags: docker, docker-compose, ubuntu-16.04, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

all,

I have setup a Hyperledger server in an Ubuntu VM instance. On the Ubuntu VM, I tried running Hyperledger Fabric-peer using the docker-compose.yml file with the following configuration:

```
membersrvc:
  image: hyperledger/fabric-membersrvc
  ports:
    - "7054:7054"
  command: membersrvc
 vp0:
  image: hyperledger/fabric-peer
  ports:
    - "7050:7050"
    - "7051:7051"
    - "7053:7053"
  environment:
    - CORE_PEER_ADDRESSAUTODETECT=true
    - CORE_VM_ENDPOINT=unix:///var/run/docker.sock
    - CORE_LOGGING_LEVEL=DEBUG
    - CORE_PEER_ID=vp0
    - CORE_PEER_PKI_ECA_PADDR=membersrvc:7054
    - CORE_PEER_PKI_TCA_PADDR=membersrvc:7054
    - CORE_PEER_PKI_TLSCA_PADDR=membersrvc:7054
    - CORE_SECURITY_ENABLED=true
    - CORE_SECURITY_ENROLLID=test_vp0
    - CORE_SECURITY_ENROLLSECRET=MwYpmSRjupbT
   links:
    - membersrvc
  command: sh -c "sleep 10; peer node start"
```

this has the same configuration suggested in this page: https://github.com/hyperledger-archives/fabric/blob/master/pub/fabric-peer.md but I encountered a problem shown in this screenshot:
[image: stucked at grpc info message]

From what I have understand, hyperledger/fabric-peer is needed to be able to do transactions on the blockchain from deploying chaincodes to performing operations on the ledger. May I know what I am doing wrong from using the above docker-compose.yml with docker-compose up command and if my understanding is correct? Are there any components that might be causing the problem with running the Hyperledger docker image?

Basically, I need to be able to deploy a chaincode and invoke the methods in the chaincode from an Ubuntu server running Hyperledger Fabric.

Thank you.

Comment: The log messages you posted are not an issue - they are just debug messages.  But looks like you are using an old compose file for Fabric v0.6.  Have you looked at the new docs / samples:   http://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.1/build_network.html

Comment: Is there a way I could deploy and invoke a chaincode using REST Protocol? Thank you.

Comment: You should be able to use the REST SDK:  https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-sdk-rest